# Windows 10 Assigned Access app removes windows.aboveLockScreen on build

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

We have a standard windows 8.1 app that we were using with assigned access on windows 8.1.

I ported the app to the new windows 10 packages and the ability to run our app in Assigned Access was removed.

Looking at [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/mt633799(v=vs.85).aspx) Tells me that I need to add the extension to the mainifest. No worries..

Then when I do a store build, deploy to test, it doesn't work. 
I re-opened the manifest to find that the one it needs gets removed every time and I cant figure out why.

Running VS 2015 on Windows 10 with javascript app.
Before the build:

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.lockScreenCall" />
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.aboveLockScreen" />
</Extensions>
```

After the build:

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.lockScreenCall" />
</Extensions>
```

What is removing it and WHY? How do I stop it???

Comment: For others: The <Extensions> element goes inside the <Application> element.

Comment: I have this problem intermittently.  It's hard to predict whether or not the extension gets cut

Comment: @SamIam I ended up just creating a totally new project and pulling in my app code without the config or manifests. Worked after that... Something in the standard template/build changed and I didn't have the patience to hunt it down. It was actually way faster to do it that way..